# Inserting Record using DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I am developing an application in which I want to insert the data from the DataSet.

Following is my code to Insert the data:

WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
 public void Recieve_Data()
    {
        DataGridView.DataSource = obj.Get_Data();
        DataGridView.DataBind();
    }

    public void Insert_Data()
    {
       TextBox StudentID = DataGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtID") as TextBox;
       TextBox StudentName = DataGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtName") as TextBox;
       TextBox StudentSex = DataGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtSex") as TextBox;
       TextBox StudentCity = DataGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtCity") as TextBox;

       int StuID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentID.Text);
       string StuName = StudentName.Text;
       string StuSex = StudentSex.Text;
       string StuCity = StudentCity.Text;

       obj.Insert_Data(StuID, StuName,StuSex, StuCity);          
       Recieve_Data();
    }
```

My Insert_Data() is:

```
public void Insert_Data(int StuID, string StuName, string StuSex, string StuCity)
    {
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds,"Student");

        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = StuID;
        dr["Name"] = StuName;
        dr["Sex"] = StuSex;
        dr["City"] = StuCity;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
    }
```

I am successfully receiving the new inserted record (seventh record) in the dataset at last:

[image]

But in the database, my table is not updated with the seventh row:

[image]

Comment: Your updated database will be in `bin` directory. Check that database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Insert_Data(int StuID, string StuName, string StuSex, string StuCity)
{
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student", con);
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder=new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds,"Student");

    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = StuID;
    dr["Name"] = StuName;
    dr["Sex"] = StuSex;
    dr["City"] = StuCity;
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
    ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
    adap.Update(ds, "Student"); 
}
```

// Note: To reflect these change in DB you have to call "Update" method of SqlDataAdapter and the update method need Insert/update/Delete command to perform these operation on DB. I have used SqlcommandBuilder  to generate the Insert/update/Delete, The Student table must have primary key to generate the insert /update /delete command using SqlcommandBuilder.

Comment: That's the problem.. no error. Still showing the 7th row but the database still not showing the inserted row.